# How can I retrieve disk space information on a remote windows machine using python?

Tags: python, windows, remote-access, diskspace

I want to write a python script that connects to a windows machine and accesses disk space information.

Currently, this works on my local machine.

```
def connect():
    c = wmi.WMI()
    for d in c.Win32_LogicalDisk():
        print(d.Caption, d.FreeSpace, d.Size)
```

I'm trying to make it work for a remote machine by making some changes.

```
def connect_windows(ip):
    connection = wmi.WMI(ip, user = "username", password = "password")
    for info in connection.Win32_LogicalDisk():
        print(info.Caption, info.FreeSpace, info.Size)
```

However, this is just giving me:

Unexpected COM Error.. The RPC server is unavailable.

I've gotten a similar process to work just fine with Linux machines, but Windows is giving me trouble. Is there a better way to approach this?

Comment: It's likely a configuration problem on the remote machine -- maybe the WMI or RPC service is disabled or maybe the firewall is blocking inbound RPC, DCOM, and/or WMI connections. For the latter, check that "Windows Management Instrumentation (WMI-In)" is enabled in the Windows firewall rules, if you're using it on the remote machine.

Comment: May it is not able to find the machine with IP. Try connecting the machine WMI through wbemtest tool.